# Como saber se está fazendo resize em width ou height?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Existe alguma forma de ver se o `resize()` da janela está ocorrendo na largura ou está ocorrendo na altura?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Guarde o [height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/) e/ou o [width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/) do objeto em uma variável e compare no callback com o valor anterior.

[**Exemplo a funcionar no JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/Mw45X/)
<sup>Alterar a largura ou altura da janela "result" para ver...</sup>

**jQuery:**

```
// guardar valores em uso
var h = $(window).height(),
    w = $(window).width();

// realizar verificação
$(window).resize(function(){

    // recolher valores actuais
    var nh = $(window).height(),
        nw = $(window).width();

    /* comparar os valores antigos com os novos
     * e realizar acção pretendida aqui!
     */

    // atualizar os valores nas variáveis que guardam o valor antigo
    h = nh; w = nw;
});
```

<sup>Crédito do exemplo para o @Anoop no SOEN [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12661128/352449).</sup>

Comment: Tem algum exemplo ai Rodrigo?

Comment: @JeffersonAlison Apliquei um exemplo na resposta do Rodrigo Deodoro, guardas os valores numa variável e através do método `resize` fazes a verificação.

Comment: Ok, Zuul.. seguinte se eu quiser por exemplo exibir um alerta "vc esta mexendo na largura/altura".. ?

Comment: @JeffersonAlison Seria algo do género `if (nh != h) alert("estás a mexer na altura"); else if (nw != w) alert("estás a mexer na altura");`. **Mas cuidado com alertas dentro do método de resize**, um resize de 100 pixeis gera 100 alertas :) Salvo se fores mesmo muito rápido a mexer esse rato ;)

Comment: Nesse caso o ideal seria pôr o bloco do $(window).resize() dentro de um bloco setTimeout de pelo menos um segundo, pra evitar que o código seja executado uma vez por pixel.

Comment: @Zuul, faço essa condição dentro do resize? Pois não consegui, é possível editar o seu código?

Comment: @JeffersonAlison Tecnicamente o código não é meu, é do Rodrigo Deodoro. Mas fica aqui um [exemplo a funcionar](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/Mw45X/), altera o tamanho da janela do resultado e vais ver a magia a acontecer.

Answer (score 2):

Tente algo deste tipo:

```
$(document).on('ready', function() {
    var width = $(window).width(), height = $(window).height();

    $(windows).on('resize', function() {
        if($(window).width() != width) {
          console.log('A largura mudou para'+$(window).width());
        }

        if($(window).height() != height) {
          console.log('A altura mudou para'+$(window).height());
        } 
    });
});
```

A minha resposta é bem parecida com a do amigo acima, mas eu já estava escrevendo quando você começou, então decidi mandar mesmo assim :)

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar a Jquery UI. Ela fornece mais funções sobre o resize.

Por exemplo, como a função retorna o Objeto e neste objeto temos a propiedade originalSize. Assim ficará mais facil de descobrir o tamanho original.

```
resize: function(event, ui) { 
    ui.originalSize.width;
}
```

A doc irá te auxiliar bastante caso tenha interesse. [Jquery Ui](http://jqueryui.com/resizable/)

Comment: Na minha opinião é desnecessário acrescentar uma biblioteca inteira somente pra uma questão tão simples...

Comment: Caso não for o resize da janela, e sim um resize de objetos, acredito que seria mais interessante o uso da biblioteca. Porém a inclusão de uma biblioteca realmente é um lado negativo desta solução.

Answer (score -1):

Não entendi direito a pergunta,Então vai alguns exemplos:

**1°** - Caso você esteja querendo obter a a largura e altura da tela assim que a tela é carregada.

```
    //Exemplo 1
    var w = $(this).width();
    var h = $(this).width();
    console.log("Largura: " + w);   //Widht
    console.log("Altura:" + h);     //Height


    //Exemplo 2
    $(window).load(function(){
        var w = $(this).width();
        var h = $(this).width();
        console.log("Largura: " + w);   //Widht
        console.log("Altura:" + h);     //Height
    });

    //Exemplo 3
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var w = $(this).width();
        var h = $(this).width();
        console.log("Largura: " + w);   //Widht
        console.log("Altura:" + h);     //Height
    });
```

**2°** - Caso você esteja querendo obter a a largura e altura da tela em quanto arrasta a tela pela ferramenta do desenvolvedor.

```
    $(window).resize(function(){
        var w = $(this).width();
        var h = $(this).width();
        console.log("Largura: " + w);   //Widht
        console.log("Altura:" + h);     //Height
    });
```

**3°** - Caso esteja querendo obter a posição atual que está na tela ou o tamanho atualinsira o código aqui:

```
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var top = $(this).scrollTop();
        console.log(top);
    });
```